# How to take picture from Camera & saved in Photo Gallery by programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iPhone Apps, I want to take pictures from Camera & save into Photo Gallery by programmatically. Is it possible in iPhone Simulator? 
so please tell me any link or materials you have.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Taking pictures from Camera is not possible in Simulator, you have to use device to test your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would use uiimagepickercontroller for this purpose. First of all, import the MobileCoreServices.framework. Then pull up the camera:

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        NSArray *media = [UIImagePickerController
                          availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

        if ([media containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage] == YES) {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            //picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
            [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]];

            picker.delegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            //[picker release];

        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsupported!"
                                                            message:@"Camera does not support photo capturing."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unavailable!"
                                                        message:@"This device does not have a camera."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
```

Then, save the photo by implementing the uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate and a save function:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Media Info: %@", info);
    NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *photoTaken = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        //Save Photo to library only if it wasnt already saved i.e. its just been taken
        if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoTaken, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }


    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    //NSLog(@"Image:%@", image);
    if (error) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                           message:[error localizedDescription]
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

More info on image:didFinishSaving.... can be found here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Also have a look at this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Comment: this is working for me correctly..my captured images are saving successfully to the device gallery but i want to know that Is it possible to save images in a particular folder(like a new album) of a gallery? thanks

Answer (score 5):

it is not possible in simulator.You have to use the device.

Answer (score 2):

I do hope you realize that the simulator does not have a camera..... So I guess thats not possible. You can definitely use a device.... You can make use of [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for capturing images.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 prerequesites needed to take a picture programmatically:

1. The device needs to have a camera check by

   ```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   ```
2. Camera controls need to be hidden (picker is a UIImagePickerController)

   ```
   picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
   ```
3. use the takePicture from UIImagePickerController

   [picker takePicture];

Side note because it did bug me for a few minutes, the takePicture method also dismisses the view.

Also posted a more complete answer here [Other Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694859/ios-taking-photo-programmatically/23312505#23312505)