# iPhone:How to get all information while to capture photo in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there any Image API to provide all information to user while he capture a photo in iPhone? and also I want to develop this functionality in iPhone so please tell me any link or any idea you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIImagePickerController to provide user with the camera to take the photo. You can get the help from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more-closed

and here:

[How to take picture from Camera & saved in Photo Gallery by programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812634/how-to-take-picture-from-camera-saved-in-photo-gallery-by-programmatically/6812786#6812786)

When the user chooses to 'Use' the photo and you get the callback to your delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` you can get the info about that photo in the info dictionary using the key UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata like this:

```
[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
```

You can use NSLog() to see what values it returns and then get them accordingly and display them as you like.