# how to save the image on iPhone, in the gallery?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

how to save the image on iPhone, in the gallery, in applications such as "wallpaper " ?

Hi :) i create app with wallpapers :) but i dont know how to save my images in gallery :( Help me please

Comment: Other people have asked similar questions in Stack Overflow as a quick search would show you. You can find a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812634/how-to-take-picture-from-camera-saved-in-photo-gallery-by-programmatically. If those did not work for you, please explain why it didn't in your question.

Comment: I have a plist file, which is a dictionary and an array of images. I need that I was staying at a particular picture, pressed the button "save" and it is saved in the gallery :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To save an image you can use this line of code:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:"someImage.png"];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

There are also ways to check when the image is done saving, the full documentation can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

On newer iOS versions, it is required by Apple that in your info.plist you add a usage descriptor for the key `Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description`. (`NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`)

Comment: From Apple's website: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
Adds the specified image to the user’s Camera Roll album.

Comment: THNX :) but what to press to save it? to prescribe what that button? or both? :)

Comment: Shabzco :) rly THNX for YOU :) I ordered what you told me :) using (IBAсtion), but it is for individual pictures :) with individual names. I have a plist file, which is a dictionary and an array of images. I need that I was staying at a particular picture, pressed the button "save" and it is saved in the gallery :)

Comment: The other way, in case you want to save image to your specific album directory, could be to use image to NSdata, and then write the data to specified path.

Comment: You can also add 'Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description' key with '$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use' value into info.plist for enable photo library from you app.